# A general expression for the summation of series with binomial coefficients : $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{k+n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I try to derive a general expression for the following summation of series:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{{n}\choose{k}} \frac{1}{k+n},$$
where $n$ is a positive integer.

I have computed it manually:
$$S_1=\frac{1}{2},\hspace{0.2cm}S_2=\frac{1}{3\times4},\hspace{0.2cm}S_3=\frac{1}{2\times5\times6},\hspace{0.2cm}S_4=\frac{1}{5\times7\times8}.$$
But I couldn't found any regularity to set a hypothesis for $S_n$.

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on the sum $S_n = \frac{2^{-2n} \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+1)}$, but your calculated terms do not match up with that.

Comment: But $S_1=\frac12$, $S_2=\frac1{12}$, $S_3=\frac1{60}$, and $S_4=\frac1{280}$.  Did you mess up the indices?

Comment: @Zvi Yes, thank you for your remind, now I've changed the indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

$$
x^{n-1}(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{{n}\choose{k}}x^{n+k-1}
$$

$$
\int \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{{n}\choose{k}}x^{n+k-1}dx = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{{n}\choose{k}}\frac{x^{n+k}}{n+k}
$$

Comment: Cool!  So, the answer is $B(n,n+1)=\frac{1}{n\,\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{1}{2n\binom{2n-1}{n}}$.

Comment: @Zvi Could you tell me how is B(m,n) defined? I'm not familiar with this function.

Comment: @yuhouCHEN  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: @Zvi Great! Now I understand the calculation, thank you all!

Comment: That was excellent! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

An overkill, just for fun. Recalling the [Melzak's identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07006) $$f\left(x+y\right)=x\dbinom{x+n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{f\left(x+y\right)}{k+x}$$ where $f$ is an algebraic polynomial up to degree $n$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R},\, x\neq-k,\,k=0,\dots,n$, we can observe, taking $f\equiv1$ and $x=n$, that $$1=n\dbinom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k+n}.$$